# How to add UIActivity Indicator to every custom UItableviewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am new to learn objective-c. I want to add `UIActivity` Indicator to every `UITableViewCell` during displaying image from server and hide them when they are `finishedloading.`

Please help me to give some sample code.

Very thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207288/correct-way-to-show-downloadable-content-in-uitableview-with-progressbar-etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747926/adding-uiactivityindicator-to-uitableview

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421673/how-do-i-add-a-uiactivity-indicator-to-every-cell-and-maintain-control-of-each-i

Answer (score 1):

You can add activity indicator in image view and start animating when image start loading from server, stop animating when you have actual image from server. Please try below code

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.center = imageView.center;// it will display in center of image view
[iamgeView addSubview:indicator];    
[indicator startAnimating]
```

call `[indicator stopAnimating]` when you have image.

Stoping animation in table view cell:
//it better you set placehod

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"if any "]
                        success:^(UIImage *image) {
                            // remove animation
                          [indicator stopAnimating];
                          [indicator removeFromSuperview];

                        }
                        failure:^(NSError *error) {

                            // handle failed download

  }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following links,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

[Lazy Load cell image for programmatically created tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083866/lazy-load-cell-image-for-programmatically-created-tableview)

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

http://www.hollance.com/2011/03/mhlazytableimages-efficiently-load-images-for-large-tables/#!